# Does Vrindavaan have some connection with Goloka? Are these two places physically connected?

Tags: krishna, goloka, vrindavana

Does the place Vrindavan located in Uttar Pradesh, the place Krishna spent his childhood have some connection with Go-Loka, the place where Krishna resides at present?

Are these two places physically connected?

Comment: Brahmavaivartapurāṇa describes Vṛndāvana to be a physical reflection of Goloka, similar to how Kailāsa is the physical reflection of Śivaloka, Śrīkṣetra Purīdhama is the physical reflection of Vaikuṇṭha & Ayodhyā is the physical reflection of Sāketaloka.

Comment: @অনু Where is Śrīkṣetra Purīdhama ? Is it Puri in Odisha ? But Odisha lies outside of Aryavrata. Is such a thing (about Puri ) mentioned in Sanskrit Puranas ?

Comment: In Skanda Purana, Purusottamaksetramahatmya, it is stated that Puri is verily the physical reflection of Vaikuntha, all the residents of Puri irrespective of caste are verily manifestations of Vishnu's attendants, so one shouldn't hesitate to accept Jagannatha's mahaprasada even from the hands of a candala within the precints of Puri.